# Linux SQL Server query with dynamic data?

Tags: sql-server, database, bash, dynamic

I am trying to run a query from a shell script

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable where sessionid = 123
```

I can do:

```
bsqldb -U myname -P mypass -S myserv -i getcount.sql
```

But that means the sessionid is hardcoded to 123

I need to have the sessionid pulled in from the shell script calling the bsqldb comment

How can I pass the sessionid as a variable?

Comment: I suppose I could just write the query to a tmp file and pass that file in

Comment: couldn't you just `echo SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable where sessionid = 123 | bsqldb -U myname -P mypass -S myserv` ?

Comment: bsqldb doesn't take queries inline.. they must come from an input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best way was to just create a tmp.sql file from the bash script itself and use that as my input:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE SessionID = $SESS_ID" > tmp.sql
result=$(bsqldb -U $USER -S $SERV -P $PASS -i tmp.sql -q)
rm -f tmp.sql
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "SELECT ${foo} FROM ${bar}" | bsqldb -U myname -P mypass -S myserv -i -
```

Watch out for SQL injection though.